# google-chrome and microsoft-edge crash on Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, 23.04

The error log:

```
[22102:22102:0426/015135.602783:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(255)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
...
[22102:22102:0426/015135.604397:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(255)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
```

The errors show up on a brand-new install of xubuntu 23.04 on older hardware (Xeon, Nvidia G218, nouveau driver, so no graphic acceleration, xfce/xfwm). (OP: did you see them under gnome?)

Launched from the command line, both `google-chrome` and `microsoft-edge` **hang**; the above errors show up and no window is opened, but there is no coredump or return to the console prompt (need to ctrl-C to get back).

`chromium` installed as a snap, under `about://gru` reports the exact same messages under *Log Messages* (at the end) but `chromium` itself runs perfectly fine.

The errors under chromium appear benign, under chrome or edge cause a catastrophic hang.

Seen on first launches for both, but tried deleting the `~/.config/chrome` and `~/.config/edge` as suggested elsewhere, no effect.

Tried to launch `chrome --disable-features=TFLiteLanguageDetectionEnabled` that is used by the snap `chromium` (again as reported by `about://gru`), no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too (using 23.04 with an nVidia card). As a workaround, I've turned off hardware acceleration (Settings > System > Use hardware acceleration when available -> turn off). Perhaps you can try that and see if it resolves the issue.